# SSL extra traffic?

Tags: ssl, cryptography

I was wondering if using SSL generates a lot more traffic than an unencrypted connection. I can imagine that the key exchange and key renewal can create a little bit of extra traffic, but the use of the symmetric algorithms should generate as much traffic as an unencrypted connection. It takes more computational power to encrypt and unencrypt them using symmetric algorithms, but the size of the exchanged data should remain the same.

Answer (score 2):

Depends on how large your unsecured traffic is. If you have an HTTP(S) connection with small requests and responses (and disconnection after that), then SSL, due to its handshake, can add much more than the size of your request and response is (5-6Kb of data per SSL/TLS handshake is easily possible). But if your requests are hundreds of KBytes (or even multimegabyte) large, then SSL part can be ignored.

Comment: Usually with SSL3/TLS an SSL-session mechanism allows to re-use an existing session which minimizes the handshake overhead.

Comment: @Robert while the mechanism exists, it must be used explicitly, i.e. the application must track connections, know when consequent connection happens, and use separate "resume" mechanism. In most usage scenarios developers work on higher level, i.e. they use some HTTPS client and just ask it to retrieve the resource. There exist other mechanisms to reduce load, but they also require more detailed control over SSL/TLS handshake than most high-level libraries and components provide.

Comment: @EugeneMayevski'EldoSCorp The Java SSL package does all that for you automatically. I would have thought OpenSSL did too but I can't swear to it; ditto .NET.